# Capture differential / delta payload in Knockout view model

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, payload, delta

I am using a KO viewmodel which interfaces a REST end-point. The REST end-point serves me plain JSON data like:

```
var data = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe
};
```

Data is then transformed to a viewModel using ko.mapping as follows:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

On the view, it is possible only a part of the data will be modified, say `firstName`. In that case, I wish to construct a payload containing:

```
{
    "firstName": "Jane"
}
```

which I can then send to my server to perform an update only on those fields.

Is there any framework or utility (possibly in KO) which already does this?

Comment: take a look at [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch).

Comment: @HeyJude Is there an OOTB utility in KO which achieves this?

Comment: Nope. There's no reason for knockout to handle all that json-related logic.